# Memory interfacing 8086

Tags: memory, interfacing

Interface 16Kx8 RAM using four numbers of 8Kx8 memory chips and ROM using two numbers of 8Kx8 EPROM chips. The address map is given as RAM starts at 00000H and ROM ends at FFFFFH.

I don't know how to solve this.please provide me the answer.

Comment: ...that depends entirely on how you've integrated the 8086 into your circuit design. We cannot really help you without significantly more context. Also, ROM is not a kind-of-RAM - please correct your terminology.

Comment: This was my university question.

Comment: Can I interface 16k×8 Ram using 4 8k×8 memorychips